# Custom C++ Static Library Not Linking (Code::Blocks)

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, codeblocks

I've spent the past two hours researching this online, to no avail - I've followed all the instructions several times.

I'm using C++11, GCC, Ubuntu 15.04, and Code::Blocks 13.12.

I am creating a custom static library. At the moment, it contains only two files: `iochannel.hpp` and `iochannel.cpp`. I compile, and all is well. A single `libpawlib.a` file is produced in `pawlib/bin/Debug`

Next, in the project that I want to *use* the static library in, I go into `Project > Build Options...`. I add the path to the .a file to `Linker settings`, and I add the folder the .a file is found in to `Search Directories > Compiler` and `> Linker` I have checked, double-checked, tripe-checked, and quadruple-checked the paths.

As long as I don't try to import from the library, build of that project is successful, and it runs. However, no matter HOW I put the `#include` statement, it says "No such file or directory" when I compile. I have tried all of the following (individually)...

```
#include <iochannel>
#include <iochannel.hpp>
#include <pawlib/iochannel>
#include <pawlib/iochannel.hpp>
#include "iochannel"
#include "iochannel.hpp"
#include "pawlib/iochannel"
#include "pawlib/iochannel.hpp"
```

There is absolutely no more instruction online than what I've already followed, as far as I can tell.

This is such a theoretically trivial thing, but I'm stumped. Can anyone help me get this working?

**EDIT:** My file structure is as follows. In one folder (actually, the root of my repository for this project), I have two folders: `pawlib` and `pawlib-test`. It contains the following important files...

- `pawlib/bin/Debug/libpawlib.a`
- `pawlib/src/iochannel.cpp`
- `pawlib/include/iochannel.hpp`

The project in `pawlib-test` is using the relative path `../pawlib/bin/Debug/libpawlib.a` or `../pawlib/bin/Debug`, depending on if it wants a file or a directory path. The absolute path fails as well. I've confirmed the files and folders exist at those paths.

**IMPORTANT:** I should not have to include pawlib's .hpp files manually, as that defeats the entire purpose of a library. I use static libraries regularly, and I *never* have to add the .hpp files or their directory to search directories.

The gcc command and its error (as produced by CodeBlocks) is as follows...

```
-------------- Build: Debug in pawlib-test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -Wall -g -std=c++11 -g -I../pawlib/bin/Debug -c /home/jason/Code/Repositories/pawlib-git/pawlib-test/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
/home/jason/Code/Repositories/pawlib-git/pawlib-test/main.cpp:2:31: fatal error: pawlib/iostream.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "pawlib/iostream.hpp"
                               ^
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

**EDIT 2:** My mistake (partly)...headers are usually imported separately from the static library. The problem is, virtually none of the tutorials or documentation mention this. It's one of those "everyone knows, so it should go without saying" type of things.

Comment: No *linker* setting will help the *compiler* find an include file. Change your *include path* so that the compiler can find `iochannel.hpp`, and as you have already done: Change the *linker path* so that the linker can find `libpawlib.a`

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the static library? I need to import that .hpp FROM the static library. You can import .hpp files from other static libraries just fine - ICU, Glib, gtkmm...

Comment: `"bla.hpp : No such file or directory"`  seems strange at the link stage. It is common at compile stage, whenever the file `bla.hpp` is not in the include search path.  If `main.cpp` is in folder `src` and `iochannel.hpp` in folder `src/pawlib` then `#include "pawlib/iochannel.hpp"` should have done the trick... Could you post the gcc command that CodeBlocks has run and the error that was printed  ? Could you try to add the path to `iochannel.hpp` in Search Directories > Compiler and `#include "iochannel.hpp"` in the code ?

Comment: I added the `.hpp` path to the Search Directories and it works. What I want to know is...why is this detail left out of almost all the tutorials? Is this NORMAL for static libraries? (I only found one which just barely mentioned it...aih.) Please post as an answer and I'll acept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got confused between static and dynamic libraries. When you are linking to a static library, you must ALSO link to the header files thereof. This is why you find both the `/usr/lib` (for static libraries) and `/usr/include` (for their headers) folders on any UNIX machine.

As francis pointed out, this has to do with the fact that I hadn't given the path to the header files. If you're on CodeBlocks, go to the `Build Options-> Search directories -> Compiler` dialog, and add the path to the folder with the `.h` or `.hpp` files.

Now it's working just peachy.